# css position: sticky не работает при js-импорте

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

К одному из div-ов сайта предостален css-параметр "position: sticky". Сам по себе он работает. Но проблема в том, что данный div не написан напрямую в коде страницы, а импортируется из другого html-файла путём импорта с помощью js-скрипта (код будет ниже), из-за чего "position: sticky" не срабатывает, и div уходит вверх при пролистывании, вместо того чтобы "залипнуть" в заданных позициях 
(Краткая версия: меню сайта импортируется из html-файла и не "прилипает" сверху окна) 
Фиксится ли такое?

```
$(function название_функции() {
    $(".html-класс").load("ссылка на html-файл");
  });
```

Comment: Так сложно что-то сказать, думаю проблема в HTML разметке/стилях.

Comment: Да, надо было дать параметр sticky на div, в который шёл импорт